# Layer switcher for OpenLayers3 (bindto replacement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach, openlayers-3

In order to generate checkbox from layers array, I am using this example: https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch04-interacting-with-raster-data-source/example-06.html. However, since this part of the code:

```
  var visible = new ol.dom.Input(document.getElementById('layer_id_' + i));
      visible.bindTo('checked', layers[i], 'visible');
```

is deprecated since v3.5.0 (I am using v3.8.2), I found out that I can change it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808639/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-input-of-undefined/%22this%20one%22):

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile();
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var checked = this.checked;
  if (checked !== layer.getVisible()) {
    layer.setVisible(checked);
  }
});

layer.on('change:visible', function() {
  var visible = this.getVisible();
  if (visible !== checkbox.checked) {
    checkbox.checked = visible;
  }
});
```

but as I am JS noob, I was wondering if someone can help me out to implement this valid code in an example above + in addition to that I would like that only one layer, for example USA layer from Geoserver WMS demo, is checked and visible on load, and others are unchecked and not visible. (I don't know how to combain this events inside "for" loop - got stuck with it)